# Print a Cython Memoryview

Tags: python, cython

I am new to Cython and have created some Cython code called `evaluate_c`.  All I am trying to do at this stage is print to the first 5 elements of temp_info which is float array - just to eyeball the data.

```
cpdef void evaluate_c(TempLogicPy engine,
    double [:] temp_info):
    print(temp_info[:5])
```

temp_info has the type:

```
('temp_info type: ', <class 'project.temp_test._memoryviewslice'>)
```

I have tried using `print(temp_info[:5])` it does not return any floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either convert it to another (printable) type:

```
 print(list(temp_info[:5]))
```

Or you interate over the elements:

```
 for i in range(temp_info.shape[0]):
      print(temp_info[i], end=" ")
 print()  # newline
```